# Reviewing posts, something better than flagging

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, review

I have been reviewing first answers on Stack Overflow, originally to find answers to flag and build my build my flag weight. However, I find myself instead providing comments to help users provide better answers. This of course defeats the original goal of building flag weight. The game aspect of Stack Overflow encourages me to simply flag posts, but I think that this will discourage new users from answering or attempting to answer.

Is there some way to encourage reviewers to provide support to new users instead of simply flagging?

Are new users discouraged when their answers are deleted?

Is it better to just flag posts than to provide comments on them?

Comment: `originally to find answers to flag and build my build my flag weight`  **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: @Will-don't-give-a I don't understand your comment. Are criticizing my original desire to build flag weight?

Comment: [Indeed, I don't think Will approves](http://www.google.com/search?q=look%20of%20disapproval).

Comment: "Something better than flagging" == **editing**. If the post is salvageable, you should edit it to make it so. Only use flags when the post in question is *completely beyond help*.

Answer (score 11):

The vast majority of questions I flag do not merit a comment (spam, not just low-quality but no-quality, etc). If the question can be improved with a comment or an edit, you should comment and/or edit and withhold the flag.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to encourage reviewers to comment?

Comment: That would depend on the reviewer's "style", I visit each post/comment in a new tab and review them prior to passing judgement. This allows me to leave a comment if necessary. But no, besides the various badges for commenting/editing there isn't much more they could do.

Answer (score 6):

Flagging is serious business. The goal of flagging is not to build up flag weight. (Where were you planning to spend it?) The goal of flagging is to improve the site's quality.

`/review` is not a place to find posts to flag. It's a place to find posts that require action. Flagging is one of the possible actions. Editing, commenting, voting are other possible actions. It's up to you as the reviewer to decide which is the most suitable in each case.

Comment: You haven't heard about the [discount you get on cheeseburgers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87732/total-10-00-flag-weight-for-10-good-flags-but-10-flag-weight-for-1-bad-flag-t) with a high enough flag rate? (See second comment.)

Comment: I understand that flagging is serious. To date I have flagged 29 posts and all were marked as valid. Please note that question for this post is ask about ways to encourage behavior other than flagging. The goal of increasing flag weight was to earn the [Deputy Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges). The description of the Deputy Badge contains a direct link to [revewing](http://stackoverflow.com/review). It appears to me that the badge description is encouraging users to use reviewing as a good soure of posts for flagging.